# Using bash in order to extract data from a HTML forum list

Tags: bash

I'm looking to create a quick script, but I've ran into some issues.

```
<li type="square"> Y </li>
```

I'm basically using wget to download a HTML file, and then trying to search the file for the above snippet. Y is dynamic and changes each time, so in one it might be "Dave", and in the other "Chris". So I'm trying to get the bash script to find

```
<li type="square"> </li>
```

and tell me what is inbetween the two. The general formatting of the file is very messy:

```
<html stuff tags><li type="square">Dave</li><more html stuff>
<br/><html stuff>   
<br/><br/><li type="square">Chris</li><more html stuff><br/>
```

I've been unable to come up with anything that works for parsing the file, and would really appreciate someone to give me a push in the right direction.

EDIT -

```
<div class="post">
                    <hr class="hrcolor" width="100%" size="1" />
                    <div class="inner" id="msg_4287022"><ul class="bbc_list"><li type="square">-dave</li><li type="square">-chris</li><li type="square">-sarah</li><li type="square">-amber</li></ul><br /></div>
                </div>
```

is the block of code that I'm looking to extract the names from. The "-" symbol is somethng added onto the list to minimize its scope, so I just get that list. The problem I'm having is that:

```
awk '{print $2}' FS='(<[^>]*>)+-' 4287022.html > output.txt
```

Only gives outputs the first list item, and not the rest.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I have added `-?` to regexp.

Answer (score 2):

You generally should not use regex to parse html files.

Instead you can use my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) to perform pattern matching on it:

```
xidel 4287022.html -e '<li type="square">{.}</li>*'
```

Or with traditional XPath:

```
xidel 4287022.html -e '//li[@type="square"]'
```

Comment: Xidel looks like a great utility; unfortunately, as of 26 April 2013, there's no prebuilt `OS X` binary, but it can be compiled from source; see [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s69/sh/ff1e78f3-a369-4855-b18f-6184ce789c45/f3511927d0fb356ce883835f2eb712e0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep -Eo "<li type=\"square\">-?(\w+)</li>" ./*` for this.

Comment: +1 for the best approach short of using an HTML parser. Here's the full solution that extracts just the element *values*, excluding the initial "-" (i.e., in the OP's example, `dave`, `chris`, …): `grep -Eo "<li type=\"square\">-[^<]+" t.html | grep -Eo '>[^>]+' | cut -c 3-`
Also note that there's no point in enclosing the `\w+` in the regex in `()`, because `grep -Eo` doesn't support capturing subgroups - at least in GNU grep 2.10 (Ubuntu 12.04)  and BSD grep 2.5.1 (OS X 10.8.3).

Answer (score 0):

```sh
awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' FS='(<[^>]*>)+' 4287022.html
```

This presents the HTML page as a table. However instead of runs of whitespace as the Field Separator, runs of HTML tags are the Field Separator. The first field in this case is the empty space at the beginning of the line. The second field in the case is the Name, so we print this.

Result

```
-dave -chris -sarah -amber
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*<li type="square"> *\([^<]*\).*/\1/p' input.html
```

Comment: Neat, but this will only work if each `<li>` element is on its own line.